# spring+ thymeleaf unable to update

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Hi I am working with spring MVC and thymeleaf and I am not able to update data from my controller as I have following code.The main problem I am facing is that my `put` method is not getting called.

```
@GetMapping("/{id}/edit")
    public String editUser(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model) {
        logger.info("++++++++++++[edit User]\n\n" + userService.findById(id));
        model.addAttribute("user", userService.findById(id));
        return "user/edit";
    }

    @PutMapping("/{id}/edit")
    public String updateUser(@PathVariable("id") int id, @ModelAttribute("user") User user, Model model) {
        logger.info("\n\n+++++++++++++++++inside Update");
        User toUpdate = userService.findById(user.getId());
        user.setUserName(user.getUserName() != null ? user.getUserName() : toUpdate.getUserName());
        user.setName(user.getName() != null ? user.getName() : toUpdate.getName());

        logger.info(user.toString());
        userService.updateUser(user);
        model.addAttribute("user", userService.findById(user.getId()));
        return "redirect:/user/" + id;
    }
```

and my html page

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/user/__${user.id}__}" method="put"
                    th:object="${user}">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="txtUserName">User-name</label> <input
                            class="form-control" id="txtUserName" placeholder="User Name"
                            th:feild="${user.userName}" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="txtName">First Name</label> <input
                            class="form-control" id="txtName" placeholder="Full Name"
                            th:feild="${user.name}" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="calDob">Date of Birth</label> <input
                            class="form-control" id="calDob" placeholder="dd/MM/yyyy" />
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" th:method="put" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
                    <a href="#" th:href="@{/user/__${user.id}__}"
                        class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</a> <a th:method="delete"
                        href="javascript:deleteUser('${user.id}');" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                </form>
```

any help will be usefull thanks

Answer (score 2):

`PUT` is not a valid argument for `method` attibute of the `form` tag. See [HTML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-method).

Valid methods are `GET` and `POST`. And as it's not a REST API, you can use `POST` method to update.

So just update your mapping from:

```
@PutMapping("/{id}/edit")
```

to

```
@PostMapping("/{id}/edit")
```

And form tag to:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/user/__${user.id}__}/edit" method="post" th:object="${user}">
```

Comment: Think you mean `th:object`

Comment: also you dont have defined in the form the action ended in "/edit"

Comment: @cralfaro thanks for the suggestion, corrected answer