# Request method 'POST' not supported error for Thymeleaf th:method="put"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I've got this error after I submit following form:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
> Request method 'POST' not supported
> org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException:
> Request method 'POST' not supported

Here is *Thymeleaf* form html tag:

```
<form th:method="put" action="/orders/3" th:object="${order}">
    ...
</form>
```

And the controller:

```
@PutMapping("/{id}")
public String update(@PathVariable("id") Long id, 
        @ModelAttribute(name = "order") OrderDto order) {
    ...
    return "redirect:/orders";
}
```

When I change `@PutMapping("/{id}")` to `@PostMapping("/{id}")` the error fix but why it's not recognize controller related method with `@PutMapping` annotation?

***UPDATE:***

This link [spring+ thymeleaf unable to update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44884794/spring-thymeleaf-unable-to-update) does not fix my problem, because I'm using `th:method` not `method` property and then it's generated html containing `POST` method with hidden input with `PUT` value. If I have to use `@PostMapping` annotation I want to know `@PutMapping` usage.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44886975/2039546

Comment: @İsmailY. I'm using `th:method` not `method`. Generated html containing `post` method with hidden input for `put`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [spring+ thymeleaf unable to update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44884794/spring-thymeleaf-unable-to-update)

Comment: @ElmarBrauch See first comment's link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-method) does not support **`PUT`** or **`DELETE`** HTTP methods for its `method` attribute.

When you use `th:method="PUT"` thymeleaf will create hidden input as below screenshot and changes method value to `POST`.

Because of this change, `@PutMapping` does not work by default, but if you do `@PostMaping` it will.

[image]

###### If you want to use it with `@PutMapping`:

You can enable this by adding `spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled=true` to your `application.properties` file. See [Spring Boot how to use HiddenHttpMethodFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34048617/spring-boot-how-to-use-hiddenhttpmethodfilter)